# Minimizing weighted complex sum under constraint

Tags: complex-analysis, optimization, complex-numbers, lagrange-multiplier

Let $a_1,\dots,a_n\in\mathbb{C}$ be given. Consider minimizing the function of $z)$
$$
f(z_1,\dots,z_n)=\left|\sum_{j=1}^n z_j a_j\right|^2
$$
under the constraint $\left|\sum_{j=1}^n z_j \right|^2=1$.

What would $(z_1,\dots,z_n)$ that minimizes $f$ be?

Naturally, I considered minimizing $\sum_{j=1}^n\sum_{k=1}^n z_j\overline{z_k} a_j\overline{a_k}$ under $\sum_{j=1}^n\sum_{k=1}^n z_j\overline{z_k} =1$ but each $z_j$, $a_j$ are not real and I do not know how to proceed.

Comment: Should it be $a_j$ instead of $a_n$ in the expression for $f$? If yes, why cannot we say, the result is always zero?

Comment: That was a typo, now it's fixed. But I do not understand why $f$ can attain 0.

Comment: Suppose, at least two a's are non-zero. Without loss of generality I may say these are $a_1$ and $a_2$. Consider $z_1 = -a_2/\sqrt{a_1\bar{a}_1+a_2\bar{a}_2\strut}$, $z_2 = a_1/\sqrt{a_1\bar{a}_1+a_2\bar{a}_2\strut}$, and $z_{j>2} = 0$. (If I'm not making a mistake anywhere)

Comment: @guest the constraint is $|z_1+z_2|=1$ and that clearly doesn't happen in your example unless $a_1\bar a_2$ is purely imaginary

Comment: @Conrad , oh... I see...

Comment: @guess I think though you were on the right track as if any two of the $a_k$'s are distinct, wlog $a_1,a_2$, you can indeed take $z_1=\frac{a_2}{|a_1-a_2|}, z_2=-\frac{a_1}{|a_1-a_2|}, z_k=0, k >2$ and you get zero, otherwise if all $a$'s are equal, the answer is obvious and independent of the $z$'s

Comment: @Conrad , you're absolutely right, I did a wrong normalization.