# Minimizing a complicated weighted complex sum under constraint

Tags: complex-analysis, optimization, complex-numbers, lagrange-multiplier

Let $a_1,\dots,a_n\in\mathbb{C}$ be given. Consider minimizing the function of $z)$
$$
f(z_1,\dots,z_n)=\left|\sum_{j=1}^n z_j a_j\right|^2
$$
under the constraint $\left|\sum_{j=1}^n z_j \right|^2=1$.

This question is somewhat trivial: the comments in [Minimizing weighted complex sum under constraint](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3510549/minimizing-weighted-complex-sum-under-constraint) show that if any two of the $a_k$'s are distinct, then $f$ attains zero.

I wonder, what if
$$
\tilde{f}(z_1,\dots,z_n)=\sum_{j=1}^n \sum_{k=1}^n z_j\overline{z_k} \beta_{jk},
$$
where $\beta_{jk}\in\mathbb{C}$ are given, $\beta_{jk}=\overline{\beta_{kj}}$, with $\left|\sum_{j=1}^n z_j \right|^2=1$? I guess this is like asking an explicit formula of an eigenvector of $(\beta_{jk})$ corresponding to the smallest eigenvalue, so asking too much?